# C# - WebClient doesn't download full size of a file on other machines

Tags: c#

I've been trying to download a file from MediaFire(using a direct link) using WebClient for a Game Cheat Scanner. On my PC everything works fine, but when i send it to my friends, the file doesn't download and when they try to run it(it's an exe) it gives "16 bit application" error. Any solutions?

Code:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient(); // Creating WebClient
wc.DownloadFile(new System.Uri(uri), fileName); // Downloading file

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); // Waiting for a second after finishing

string exePath = ""; // Getting the exe path depending on the type
if (isCheatScan)
{
    exePath = cheatPath[bIndex];
}
else
{
    exePath = shortPath[bIndex];
}
Process p = new Process(); // Creating a new process
p.StartInfo.FileName = exePath; // Setting the file name
p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas"; // Giving administrator rules
try // Trying to run the process
{
    label1.Text = "Status: Running...";
    p.Start();
    processRunning = true;

    p.WaitForExit();

    processClosed(exePath);
 }
catch
{
}
```

EDIT: The problem was in the link I was using, since it was MediaFire and is only direct for me. Uploaded files to Google Drive and converted the link, everything is okay right now.
Thanks for your responses!

Comment: Are you compiling this as a non-64bit architecture?

Comment: @Glitch100 how do i check?

Comment: Have they tried running the downloaded file manually, to see if it didn't get corrupted during transfer.

Comment: @Skami i download it using the program and it works fine, i don't think that the file gets corrupted during the transfer.

Comment: I think I got it! When they try to open the link, it isn't direct. I uploaded the files to mediafire and then got the direct download using the download button. Is this the problem?

Comment: @TsvetomirBonev, the download link behind the button could be generated and might expire. So using it for a longer period might not be possible.

Comment: I'm willing to bet your exePath is wrong and it's trying to run a file that doesn't exist

Comment: I found the solution! The problem was in the link, because it was a mediafire link. It isn't direct for them, because they aren't logged in with my account. I uploaded the file to another file hosting website and all is okay right now.

Comment: @TsvetomirBonev Then publish it as solution. Might help someone.